# Change appendChild function

Tags: javascript, object, pdf, dom, appendchild

so I have this script to decode b64 string to pdf

```
// JavaScript Document
function decode() {
    // The Base64 string of a simple PDF file
    var b64decode = BASE64 STRING

    // Decode Base64 to binary and show some information about the PDF file (note that I skipped all checks)
    var bin = atob(b64decode);


    // Embed the PDF into the HTML page and show it to the user
    var obj = document.createElement('object');
    obj.style.width = '100%';
    obj.style.height = '842pt';
    obj.type = 'application/pdf';
    obj.data = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + b64decode;
    document.body.appendChild(obj);

    // Insert a link that allows the user to download the PDF file
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.innerHTML = 'Download PDF file';
    link.download = 'file.pdf';
    link.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + b64decode;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
}
```

And the script creates an object at the bottom of the page. Instead, I need the script to create an object inside an empty div container.

As you might guessed, I'm not a JS expert (or amateur neither)

Thanks!

Comment: Try with https://pdfkit.org/

Answer (score 0):

This line of your code does the appending:

```
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

You would have to change it to your `div`. For that you need to give your `div` an id:

```
<div id="pdf-div"></div>
```

And now you can replace the `appendChild` directive with:

```
document.getElementById('pdf-div').innerHTML = link;
```